# Sending string arrays to php

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, android-json

I want to send string array to php by Json and retrieve there.

```
String[] Books = {"book1", "book2", "book3", "book4",..};
```

In Json:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("books", Books));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
...
```

In php side:

```
$books = $_POST['books'];
$result = json_decode($books);    // is this OK?
```

Or Can I use it like below?

```
$book1 = $result[0];
```

Comment: if u send data as Json then u need json_decode() but for row data without any json format the post data will be in array form.

Comment: I'm sending by json. The thing is that I'm not sure if this method is true or not. Is `$result` and array or not. Is `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("books", Books));` a good method for sending string array or should I use `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("books", Books[]));` here?

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonString = '["xxx@gmail.com","yy@gmail.com","rr@gmail.com"]';
$arrayOfYourEmails=json_decode($jsonString);
```

Or

```
$jsonString = "[\"xxx@gmail.com\",\"yy@gmail.com\",\"rr@gmail.com\"]";
$arrayOfYourEmails=json_decode($jsonString);
```

and yes your this code is right

```
$books = $_POST['books'];
$result = json_decode($books);
```

Comment: In `$arrayOfYourEmails=json_decode($jsonString);` you are decoding a static `$jsonString`. But I need to decode `String[] Books = ["book1", "book2", "book3", "book4",...]`.